# Insert a record for each field filled out

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an object named Activity__c that has several picklist fields. For reporting, I need a way to aggregate the data from the picklist fields in a standardized fashion. When Picklist1__c, Picklist2__c, Picklist3__c, and Picklist4__c are filled out on an Activity__c record, I need the system to insert ActivityMetric__c records for each picklist. Completing one Activity__c record should insert four ActivityMetric__c records.

The code should also update an ActivityMetric__c when a picklist is updated on the parent Activity__c record.

What I've written so far does not handle updates. I know my logic is wrong too because I need all four picklist values to insert instead of only one. See below.

Will you please help? Thank you in advance!

```
public class ActivityMetric {

public static void reportingMetric (List<Activity__c> activities) {

    List<ActivityMetric__c> metrics = new List<ActivityMetric__c>();

    // For each Activity processed by the trigger, add a new
    // ActivityMetric record for the specified metrics.

    for (Activity__c newActivity : activities) {
        if(newActivity.Picklist1__c != null) {
            metrics.add(new ActivityMetric__c(
                Activity_ID__c = newActivity.Id,
                Category__c = newActivity.Metric_Category__c,
                Activity__c = newActivity.Activity__c,
                Question__c = 'Question 1',
                Response__c = newActivity.Picklist1__c
            ));
        } else if(newActivity.Picklist2__c != null) {
            metrics.add(new ActivityMetric__c(
                Activity_ID__c = newActivity.Id,
                Category__c = newActivity.Metric_Category__c,
                Activity__c = newActivity.Activity__c,
                Question__c = 'Question 2',
                Response__c = newActivity.Picklist2__c
            ));
        } else if(newActivity.Picklist3__c != null) {
            metrics.add(new ActivityMetric__c(
                Activity_ID__c = newActivity.Id,
                Category__c = newActivity.Metric_Category__c,
                Activity__c = newActivity.Activity__c,
                Question__c = 'Question 3',
                Response__c = newActivity.Picklist3__c
            ));
        } else if(newActivity.Picklist4__c != null) {
            metrics.add(new ActivityMetric__c(
                Activity_ID__c = newActivity.Id,
                Category__c = newActivity.Metric_Category__c,
                Activity__c = newActivity.Activity__c,
                Question__c = 'Question 4',
                Response__c = newActivity.Picklist4__c
            ));
        }
    }

    insert metrics;
}
}
```

Comment: Question:  How do the activity Metric records know which Picklist value controls it?  Meaning, if you enter values for Pick1, Pick2, Pick3, and Pick4, and then 4 metric records are added to the system, if at a later date the Pick1 value changes, how does the logic know which (or is it ALL) metric needs to be updated?

Comment: Only the ActivityMetric__c record that corresponds to the picklist should be updated if the picklist value changes on the Activity__c record. I could add a field that would add the API name of the Activity__c picklist field to the ActivityMetric__c record so it could be easily identified. I was originally thinking that the Question__c field could be used to find existing ActivityMetric__c records for Activity__c records that are updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, because you had an else if, once it evaluated one and if it found it was true, it was skipping the others. The way I have create is to have 4 independent ifs and to keep the DRY (Do no Repeat Yourself) format of the code I've added a method which has the purpose of create and return an ActivityMetric.

```
    for (Activity__c newActivity : activities) {
        if(newActivity.Picklist1__c != null) {
           String question = 'Question 1';
           metrics.Add(createNewActivityMetric(newActivity, newActivity.Picklist1__c,question));
        } 
        if(newActivity.Picklist2__c != null) {
           String question = 'Question 2';  
           metrics.Add(createNewActivityMetric(newActivity,newActivity.Picklist2__c,question)); 
        }
        if(newActivity.Picklist3__c != null) {
           String question = 'Question 3';
           metrics.Add(createNewActivityMetric(newActivity,newActivity.Picklist3__c,question)); 
        } 
        if(newActivity.Picklist4__c != null) {
           String question = 'Question 4';
           metrics.Add(createNewActivityMetric(newActivity,newActivity.Picklist4__c,question)); 
        }
    }

    public ActivityMetric__c createNewActivityMetric(Activity__c newActivity, String picklist, String question){
           return new ActivityMetric__c(
             Activity_ID__c = newActivity.Id,
             Category__c = newActivity.Metric_Category__c,
             Activity__c = newActivity.Activity__c,
             Question__c = question,
             Response__c = picklist
           );
    }

    insert metrics;
```

Comment: I am getting the error "expecting a semi-colon, found '('" with the `public ActivityMetric__c createNewActivityMetric(Activity__c newActivity, String picklist, String question){` line. I put a semi-colon after the `new ActivityMetric(...);` What needs to be changed?

Comment: I forgot to put the semi-colon after the creation of new ActivityMetric__c, also added the return before the new ActivityMetric__c. Also HomerJ make a valid point, can you answer the question about the update?

Comment: My code matches when you revised with the `return` and `);` but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see any other problems with the format of the code in my answer. I'm not sure why you are getting the error without looking at your code, sorry.

Comment: Did you had any luck implementing the code? and also finding a solution for the update ?

Comment: The code works for insert when I don't follow the DRY principle.  I have not been able to figure out update yet.  I'm working on a map.

Comment: I might have an idea for the update. Also I'm really curios why the method does not work to insert. Maybe we can do another remote desktop session